# Access a field with spaces in mongodb update statement

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have following document fields in a collection

```
{
     _id: ObjectId("5f1b6b26ea1c3b378704b7e9"),
     "Gene Name":"xyz"
}
```

I am trying to add a new field but without spaces. How can I do that ? as the following didn't work

```
db.getCollection('collection').updateMany(
   { },
   { $set: { "geneName": "$'Gene Name'" } }
)
```

And also this didn't work either

```
db.getCollection('collection').find({}).forEach( function(doc) 
    { 
       db.getCollection('collection').updateOne(
          {_id:doc._id },
          { $set: { "geneName": doc.Gene Name } }
       );
    } );
```

Please note I do not want to RENAME the existing field. I simply want to access the current field to add it to a new field.

I will appriciate if you can provide the solution for both forEach and the aggregation pipeline (if either of these are possible for such operation) as I want to learn how to access such annoying fields using "${field}" notation as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MongodDB version 4.2+ you can use an aggregation pipeline in the `updateOne`, `updateMany` or `update` collection methods. Here is what you need:

```
db.collection.update({},
[
  {
    $set: {
      "anotherfield": "$Gene Name"
    }
  }
])
```

The result will be:

```
  {
    "Gene Name": "xyz",
    "_id": ObjectId("5f1b6b26ea1c3b378704b7e9"),
    "anotherfield": "xyz"
  }
```

Playground: https://mongoplayground.net/p/-kfY7sqNlBm

Comment: Thank you . I dont know before your when I tried it why it didn't work. now it is working. Do you know how to access such fields (with spaces) in for each approach?

Comment: @Shahan The reason your code did not work is because you were not using the aggregation pipeline in your `updateMany` statement. Note how you're missing the `[...]` around your `$set` object. adding the brackets turns your update into a pipeline and only then can you use variables like `"$Gene Name"`